# JVM Performance - JVM performance not scaling with number of processors

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, multiprocessing, cpu

**Summary**

I am doing a million floating point divisions in different threads, these threads share nothing from programmer's point of view i.e. no explicit locks are involved.

Following are the perf numbers when I ran `java  -jar /tmp/my-exps-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 1000000 100` on machines having 8, 16 and 32 vcores (n/2 cores with 2 threads per core).

- 1000000 is number of floating point divisions that each thread does, 100 is number of threads.
- All the processors belonged to same family - Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8175M CPU @ 2.50GHz.
- Using htop, I was seeing a 100% usage for all the cores when the program was running.

```
====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 8 
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 3156601 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 31566.01
====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 16
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 3297807 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 32978.07

====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 32
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 3448590 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 34485.9

====================================
```

**Expectation**

I expected it to scale linearly with number of cores i.e execution time should decrease in proportion to increase in CPU cores. However the above numbers are totally opposite. It increases by a small fraction with increment in vcores :D

Not very sure but some guesses that I made

- Context switch time increases with number of cores ?
- Some implicit locks are taken on data and those become more expensive as the race increase with number of cores.

**Code Details**

Thread

```
    private static class BenchmarkThread implements Callable<BenchmarkResult> {
        private final long numOperationsPerThread;

        private BenchmarkThread(long numOperationsPerThread) {
            this.numOperationsPerThread = numOperationsPerThread;
        }

        @Override
        public BenchmarkResult call() {
            double sum = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (long i = 0; i < numOperationsPerThread; i++) {
                double numerator = RANDOM.nextDouble();
                double denominator = RANDOM.nextDouble();
                double result = numerator / denominator;
                sum += result;
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return new BenchmarkResult(Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                    (end - start),
                    sum);
        }
    }
```

Driver (yes `resultFuture.get()` blocks but we are not counting that time, we are doing a sum of individual thread times `timeToComplete += benchmarkResult.timeToCompleteMillis`)

**Complete runnable example(edited - see EDIT 1 below)**

```
public class VerticalScalingExp {

    private final long numOperationsPerThread;
    private final int numThreads;

    private final List<Future<BenchmarkResult>> benchMarkResultsFuture;
    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    public VerticalScalingExp(long numOperationsPerThread, int numThreads) {
        this.numOperationsPerThread = numOperationsPerThread;
        this.numThreads = numThreads;

        this.benchMarkResultsFuture = new ArrayList<>(numThreads);
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        long numOperationsPerThread;
        int numThreads;
        if (args.length != 2) {
            numOperationsPerThread = 1000000;
            numThreads = 50;
        } else {
            numOperationsPerThread = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            numThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }

        new VerticalScalingExp(numOperationsPerThread, numThreads).runBenchmark();
    }

    private void runBenchmark() throws Exception {
      try {
          System.out.println("[START]====VerticalScalingExp.runBenchmark====" );
          System.out.println("numOperationsPerThread = " + numOperationsPerThread + ", numThreads = " + numThreads);
          Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
          System.out.println("runtime.maxMemory() = " + runtime.maxMemory());
          System.out.println("runtime.freeMemory() = " + runtime.freeMemory());
          System.out.println("runtime.availableProcessors() = " + runtime.availableProcessors());
          long timeToComplete = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
              benchMarkResultsFuture.add(executorService.submit(new BenchmarkThread(numOperationsPerThread)));
          }

          for (Future<BenchmarkResult> resultFuture : benchMarkResultsFuture) {
              BenchmarkResult benchmarkResult = resultFuture.get();
              System.out.println("resultFuture.get() = " + benchmarkResult);
              timeToComplete += benchmarkResult.timeToCompleteMillis;
          }
          double avg = (double) timeToComplete / numThreads;
          System.out.println("=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in " + timeToComplete +
                  " millis ======== average time to complete one thread = " + avg );


      } finally {
          executorService.shutdown();
      }
    }

    private static class BenchmarkThread implements Callable<BenchmarkResult> {
        private final long numOperationsPerThread;

        private BenchmarkThread(long numOperationsPerThread) {
            this.numOperationsPerThread = numOperationsPerThread;
        }

        @Override
        public BenchmarkResult call() {
            double sum = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ThreadLocalRandom random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
            for (long i = 0; i < numOperationsPerThread; i++) {
                double numerator = random.nextDouble();
                double denominator = random.nextDouble();
                double result = numerator / denominator;
                sum += result;
            }
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return new BenchmarkResult(Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                    (end - start),
                    sum);
        }
    }

    private static class BenchmarkResult {
        private final String threadName;
        private final long timeToCompleteMillis;
        private final double sum;

        public BenchmarkResult(String threadName, long timeToCompleteMillis, double sum) {
            this.threadName = threadName;
            this.timeToCompleteMillis = timeToCompleteMillis;
            this.sum = sum;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BenchmarkResult{" +
                    "threadName='" + threadName + '\'' +
                    ", timeToCompleteMillis=" + timeToCompleteMillis +
                    ", sum =" + sum +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- I found this blog - https://www.theserverside.com/feature/Why-Java-Applications-Fail-to-Scale-Linearly which explains very nicely about data collisions that happen with increase in number of cores, is the code above suffering from the same ? (But in my code I am not sharing anything among threads ?) If yes, at what level these collisions are happening, Heap ? CPU caches ? something else ?
- Is this a commonly observed pattern ? (perf does not scale linearly with cpu cores)
- What can be done to make it scale as expected ?

Apologies for the long post :) Thanks :)

**EDIT 1:**

As suggested in comments and answer, I tried using ThreadLocalRandom.
Performance increases a lot as compared to previous cases but still, performance decreases with increase in cores.

```
====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 8 
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 1683 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 16.83

====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 16
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 6622 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 66.22

====================================

runtime.availableProcessors() = 32
=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 19924 millis ======== average time to complete one thread = 199.24

====================================
```

Comment: Please show a complete, runnable example.

Comment: Thanks for checking @StanislavBashkyrtsev  I invoked the same number of operations (numOperationsPerThread) in each thread. 
I have updated the full code in the question under "Complete runnable example"

Comment: `Random.nextDouble()` calls `Random.next()` twice. `Random.next()` uses an internal field `AtomicLong seed` with `seed.compareAndSet()` which is synchronization point between the threads (i.e. it is required that all threads see the same seed value). Replace the global `RANDOM` instance with a per-thread `Random` generator.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKläger, will run with per thread random generator.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Updated in "EDIT 1:" with ThreadLocalRandom observations.

Answer (score 4):

This could be the cause of the problem:

```
  private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
```

Because this is contended between all threads.

Try a ThreadLocalRandom instead.

Also, I would use a more reliable benchmarking approach like JMH.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, sure will try.

Comment: Updated in "EDIT 1:" with ThreadLocalRandom observations.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're measuring what you think you're measuring. You have 100 tasks and you measure how much time each task takes to finish. Suppose each takes 2sec. So if we execute them one after another it'll be 2sec * 100.

Now suppose you run them in 8 threads and 8 cores. This doesn't (ideally) change the amount of time each task takes, so you still have 2sec for each task. And you again have 2sec * 100 of *summed* time. But the overall execution time changes - it's `(2sec * 100) / 8` because this *summed* time is now spread across 8 cores instead of 1.

So what you need to measure is the total time it takes for the program to run. Just measure it in `runBenchmark()` method:

```
private void runBenchmark() throws Exception {
  try {
      long started = System.nanoTime();
      for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
          benchMarkResultsFuture.add(executorService.submit(new BenchmarkThread(numOperationsPerThread)));
      for (Future<BenchmarkResult> resultFuture : benchMarkResultsFuture)
          resultFuture.get();

      long timeToComplete = (System.nanoTime() - started) / 1000;
      System.out.println("=====runBenchmark() FINISHED in " + timeToComplete);
  } finally {
      executorService.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: I get your point about dividing total number of operations among threads. But here I think we are more concerned about the number of these threads that cores can service and there we are seeing lesser number of cores winning due to some reason.

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, in your question you stated that you expect the time to decrease. Which doesn't make sense. If you're adding x2 cores but also add x2 work, then why would that finish faster?

Comment: The amount of work is constant in all the setups. All 8, 16, and 32 cores systems are getting to process 100 threads and 1M operations in each thread. Then we can expect a perf gain, is that right ?

Comment: I clarified it a bit more in the question - "1000000 is number of floating point divisions that each thread does, 100 is number of threads."

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, ah, so you're not increasing the number of threads - it's always 100 regardless of whether you're running on the machine with 8 or 32 cores? If that's the case, then sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, I think now I see the problem and my answer is not far off. Let me update it :)

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, take a look now. Hopefully it answers the question now :)

Comment: No worries and thanks for updating again. Actually I did that earlier and I understand what you are measuring is the total time to complete the program with overlapping threads being run concurrently. For the same purpose I was calculating the average time. 
Anyways, I ran it with your implementation of runBenchmark() and I am seeing similar results - 
1. On 8 cores - =====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 171217
2. On 16 cores - =====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 186911
3. On 32 cores - =====runBenchmark() FINISHED in 267623 

As we can see, the time is increasing with number of cores.

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, that's interesting.. Maybe it's the ThreadPoolExecutor which has issues with threads constantly fighting for tasks. Could you increase the number of operations? If the trend improves, that again would point to the fact that the culprit is somewhere in the thread pool. If that's the case, try ForkJoinPool. It's supposed to be more performant in such scenarios.

Comment: Sure Stanislav, I will try.